# How to get pointers from range-based loop / for_each in VS2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, boost, c++11

I'm using Visual Studio 2010. One feature I'd like to use, what has been left out of VS2010, but is included in VS2012 is the range-based for-loop.

In VS2012 you can do neat and super-tidy for-loops like:

```
for( auto& it: myElements )
    it->something();
```

So far, the closest I could get in VS2010 is this syntax:

```
for( auto it = myElements.begin(), end = myElements.end(); it != end; it++ )
    it->something();
```

Upon reading some related questions, I found that using boost\foreach I have access to the following macro:

```
BOOST_FOREACH( auto it, myElements ){
    it.something();
}
```

My problem with this method is that it gives a **copy** (or something similar), not a **pointer**. Here is where I get confused. The [foreach reference](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/foreach.html) says the following:

> It does no dynamic allocations, makes no virtual function calls or
>   calls through function pointers, and makes no calls that are not
>   transparent to the compiler's optimizer.

What does it mean? Isn't it a copy?

How can I get a pointer back from BOOST_FOREACH? Or should I use some other boost function?

I've seen this syntax in other questions here:

```
BOOST_FOREACH( auto& it, myElements ){
    it->something();
}
```

however this doesn't compile for me and throws errors in the editor. What's wrong with this? Why did I find it as a valid code on many other questions here?

Are there any nice and tidy solution in VS2010 for a range-based for-loop? (including using boost)

Comment: Unrelated but with for range loops you don't have to dereference anything.

Comment: If I try to modify anything in a `it.setSomething( 0 )` way it disappears.

Comment: You do know some iterators get invalidated if modified right?

Comment: I'm guessing it's a reference? Besides, use `std::for_each`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main question is, do you have a container of pointers? Even in VS2012, `for(auto& it: myElements) it->something();` only works on containers of (smart) pointers. The `&` tells you that `it` is a reference, and the `->` tells you that it's a pointer. That's not a contradiction; you can have references to pointers.

But why would you want a pointer anyway? A reference is far more idiomatic.

Comment: Thanks for this, it seems the project I've seen it used smart pointers extensively, so it was standard (but confusing) to write that line. The other part of the confusion was that almost all examples in the [boost reference page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/foreach.html) are without &, like `std::list<int> list_int( /*...*/ );
BOOST_FOREACH( int i, list_int )
{
    // do something with i
}` and and here the // do something with i is highly confusing. Isn't it just a copy of the original object when not using reference in the FOR_EACH?

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

> In VS2012 you can do neat and super-tidy for-loops like:
>
> ```
> for( auto& it: myElements )
>     it->something();
> ```

The range based loop returns a reference to an object:

```
for(auto& element: myElements)
    element.something();
```

*edit*

The first syntax would be valid if the objects stored in the container were either pointers, or objects of a class which overloaded `operator*`, such as smart pointers.

Comment: Thanks for this, the second code part helped me fix the problem, but it seems the first case can be valid in case of using smart pointers.